# Stacked elements mix-blend-mode [Safari]

Tags: html, css, animation, safari, frontend

I'm developing a website with a custom scrollbar which changes its colour depending on what background it is on: https://nimb.ws/v58Bum

Here's the demo: https://why404.lt/en/our-company

This effect is achieved by having 4 elements stacked on top of each other with different z-index, mix-blend-mode and background-color properties. It works cool in Chrome, Firefox but does not in Safari.

Now I do understand that this is a rather unconventional approach but maybe someone knows a way how to make this work in Safari?

Appreciate any help!

Here's the CSS:

````
.scrollbar-thumb-y.clone
  left: unset
  right: 7.5%
  width: 4px
  background-color: unset
  top: 83px
  &.clone--1
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px)
    z-index: 4
  &.clone--2
    z-index: 5
    mix-blend-mode: overlay
    background-color: #2f2f2f
  &.clone--3
    z-index: 6
    mix-blend-mode: difference
    background-color: #fff
  &.clone--4
    z-index: 7
    mix-blend-mode: color
    background-color: #0681DA
```
````